# How do you hide file extension of page, one example of that is pinterest?

Tags: url, file-extension, pinterest

I want to know how do they hide file extension of page like something.jsp or something.php ....for example pinterest, when you open any pin you have URL like http://pinterest.com/pin/7074097056836/

```
1.they dont show file extension.
2.If I am suppose to do, I would do like http://pinterest.com/pin.jsp?id=7074097056836
```

please guide me for this. thanks

Comment: This is commonly done using `mod_rewrite` for php/apache. A much cleaner solution however is to use a system that is not based on files but on a router (for python this is the WSGI system). If you are getting started on this, please take the time to look at this solution before jumping to something like `mod_rewrite`

Comment: I couldn't get what you mean, can you elaborate more on this.

Comment: On `mod_rewrite`: When your server receives a URL like the on from pinterest, `mod_rewrite` will internally do a replace so it looks like the one you created. The user does not see this and the webpage still handles URLs with parameters. It basically converts the URL format. On WSGI: No need to understand WSGI itself, just take a look at [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/). It uses a completely different approach where you would say there's a file called `pin.jsp` and it gets called when a user calls `/pin/{id}`. Then `id` will contain `7074097056836`. The create the mapping yourself.

Comment: That's what URL rewritting is